# NodeJS won't connect to local DB with node-mysql

Tags: mysql, ajax, node.js, express, node-mysql

I'm having an issue with NodeJS and node-mysql. For some reason, in my local environment, I'm able to connect to the database and access the endpoints to update and insert information. I'm using mac os x Sierra for development. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dev server and i'm just running node on port 80.

My connection.js file looks like this.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

function Connection() {
  this.pool = null;

  this.init = function() {
    this.pool = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit: 100,
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'Miguel',
      password: 'thepassword',
      database: 'lavishwebLogin',
     port:'3306'
    });
  };

  this.acquire = function(callback) {
    this.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      callback(err, connection);
    });
  };
}

module.exports = new Connection();
```

My endpoint looks like this...

```
this.login = function(req, res){
        connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
            con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = "' + req.Email + '";', function(err, result) {
                if(!err){
                    if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.Password, result[0].Pass) == true){
                        result[0].Pass = "";
                        res.send(result[0])
                        con.release();
                    } 
                } else {
                    res.send(err)
                    con.release()
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

the error I'm getting an error response in the console that reads like this

I'm getting an error in the terminal as well that reads like this.

build.js:1275 POST http://lavishweb.com/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at /root/syn-tacticsolutions/api/users/users.js:38:13
    at /root/syn-tacticsolutions/connection.js:18:7

And before you say it has to do with permissions...
I called this from within the v-server

```
mysql -u Miguel -p

Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 28
Server version: 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I've looked everywhere to find out why it might not be working. I'm truly stumped at this point.

Comment: This seems no nodejs issue: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is on network level. Can you do "telnet localhost 3306" from your dev server?

Comment: It says unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: @MiguelCabrera change localhost  and make it IP address

Comment: You either need to run a local mysql on your dev server or replace "localhost" to the IP of your laptop (but I asuume that is not working, normally local network are NATed). -- Maybe find someone who explains you a bit more about DNS, IPs and networks would help, too. :)

Comment: @CFrei My local mysql installation is working on my laptop, but I don't want to edit my local mysql database, I'm using the ajax requests to edit the local mysql schema. I can hit the IP just fine. I'm able to navigate to the NodeJS server's main page, but when I make an ajax request I get a bad gateway error.

Comment: @krishn patel, I have already tried that (Mac doesn't allow localhost, only 127.0.0.1 otherwise it will look for the socket as opposed to the port.) Thank you though.

Comment: I'm thinking that it has something to do with the mysql credentials because the connection.acquire() function is returning an error instead of a connection and when I try to run con.query I get an error that says that cannot read property query of undefined. Which means that there is no connection. I've even tried root with the root password and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MiguelCabrera can you try without port and connectionLimit ?

Comment: @krishn patel I'll do that next and let you know how it goes

Comment: On the production MySQL server, you might have permission to connect, but not necessarily permission to access the database or table (or column) in question. Connect to the server using the command-line client again, but this time issue your query as well.

Comment: I tried that and I tried it with the root login and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here is an update everyone. I tried curl -v http://127.0.0.1/api/users and I got the following error      curl -v http://127.0.0.1/api/users
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I found the problem. So for some reason localhost is not correct when connecting to a database server that is on the same system. What I ended up having to do was create a user for the static external IP address(not 127.0.0.1) of my remote server and then access it using that user.

```
mysql -u root -p
password: thepassword

>create user 'user'@'ip' identified by 'thepassword';
>grant all on *.* to 'user'@'ip';
>flush privileges;
>exit;

 this.init = function() {
   this.pool = mysql.createPool({
     host: 'ip',
     user: 'user',
     password: 'thepassword',
     database: 'table'
   });
 };
```

And everything works. Yay!!

Comment: That's what I was talking about. 'user'@'' is a different than 'user'@'localhost' or 'user'@'%'.